# Change the background in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I'm getting the Co-ordinates of the mouse on the window , I'm also changing the background color using KeyListner

- Letter B for Black
- W for White
- G for green
- .......

but when I change the background color , only the background of the label is changing and not the entire window ,what I need is to change the entire window and not just the label , any ideas why is that ?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
public class mouseCrd extends JFrame {
private JPanel contentPane;
public mouseCrd() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 650, 650);
    setTitle("Mouse co-ordinates");
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(0, 0, 650, 650);
    contentPane.add(panel);
    JLabel label = new JLabel(".................");
    label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 30));
    panel.add(label);
    panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            label.setText("X = "+ e.getX()+" ; Y = "+e.getY());
        }
    });
    addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            super.keyReleased(e);
            int clr = e.getKeyChar();
            if(clr==KeyEvent.VK_B)
            {
                System.out.println("B is pressed");
                label.setOpaque(true);
                label.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                add(label);
            }
            else if(clr==KeyEvent.VK_W)
            {
                System.out.println("B is pressed");
                label.setOpaque(true);
                label.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                add(label);
            }
            else if(clr==KeyEvent.VK_R)
            {
                System.out.println("B is pressed");
                label.setOpaque(true);
                label.setBackground(Color.RED);
                add(label);
            }
            else if(clr==KeyEvent.VK_O)
            {
                System.out.println("B is pressed");
                label.setOpaque(true);
                label.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
                add(label);
            }
            else if(clr==KeyEvent.VK_G)
            {
                System.out.println("B is pressed");
                label.setOpaque(true);
                label.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                add(label);
            }
        }
    });
}
    public static void main(String[] args){
                EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            mouseCrd frame = new mouseCrd();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: rather than using `label.setBackground(Color.BLACK);` you need to target the JPanel or JFrame background. To change the JFrame that your code is extending using the `this` keyword like so `this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);`, however, your JPanel looks like the top component, so this will be what you want `panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);`

Comment: *only the background of the label is changing and not the entire window* - I would hope so. Think about your statement for a minute. Why would you think the background of the frame should change when you change the background of a label? The point of having individual components is that you can change the properties of individual components. How could you ever write an application if changing the property of one of the components affected all other components?

Comment: Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Also, you can't set the background of the frame directly because the frame is covered by the "content pane". So to set the background of the frame you really need to do: `frame.getContentPane().setBackground(....)`, See the Swing tuturial on [Using Top Level Containers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) for an overview of Swing design.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change the background of your aplication, you have to change the background of the JPane that contains all your components, you are doing:
`label.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);`
which is okay if you want to change the background of the label, this is explicit on the instruction, i did some changes in your code, look at this:

```
public class mouseCrd extends JFrame {
    public mouseCrd() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 650, 650);
        setTitle("Mouse co-ordinates");
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);


        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 650, 650);
        add(panel);

        JLabel label = new JLabel(".................");
        label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 30));

        panel.add(label);
        panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                label.setText("X = "+ e.getX()+" ; Y = "+e.getY());
            }
        });

        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                super.keyReleased(e);
                char keyPressed = e.getKeyChar();
                if(keyPressed=='b')
                {
                    System.out.println("B is pressed");
                    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                else if(keyPressed=='w')
                {
                    System.out.println("W is pressed");
                    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                }
                else if(keyPressed=='r')
                {
                    System.out.println("R is pressed");
                    panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
                }
                else if(keyPressed=='o')
                {
                    System.out.println("O is pressed");
                    panel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
                }
                else if(keyPressed=='g')
                {
                    System.out.println("G is pressed");
                    panel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
       new mouseCrd();
    }
}
```

I removed the contentPane because it was useless an then in the key released, i just change the backgound of the panel JPane with the method setBackground(), and i removed the use of the KeyEvent constants because is easier to use chars

Answer (score 0):

I know what you already get the needed answer, but I would like to recommend you the Oracle Documentation regarding Swing and GUI's.

Its begginer friendly  and it stress exactly what you need to know to have good fundaments.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html